# How to properly connect metallic conductors to graphite electrodes?

Tags: conductors, interconnect, electrode

I want to prepare graphite electrodes for electrolytic experiments.

I am therefore looking for good ideas on how to get very intimate, long term stable and low resistance connection between the conductors (copper or aluminum or brass) and graphite.

The graphite electrodes can be rods (5...20 mm diameter, 5...20 cm long) or plates (5x5 up to 10x15 cm wide an 5...10 mm thick).

[Datasheet of a material canditate](https://www.graphite24.de/media/pdf/56/c3/d5/G24_TDS-ECO.pdf)

The current might go up to 25A, temperature of the electrolyte will range from 10 to 80 °C.

Edit: Would a large plate like 15x10x0.5cm require multiple connection points or is it conductive enough to get an even distribution of current density over the whole wetted area?

Comment: The old 1.5V carbon-zinc battery has a carbon rod down the middle, with metal top-electrode already attached...don't know if it will handle 20A though.

Comment: Solid graphite? I would think for the plates you could just through-bolt copper ring terminals. For the rods, maybe use ground rod connectors.

Comment: Long term stable in your case means corrosion resistant first. Think about gold-plated copper and stainless steel (nuts and bolts like these are available).

Comment: Just [read this](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~kovar/hall.html) and be happy. ;) That said, you might look up electroless plating.